# Java FX: Partly change the color in a ListView?

Tags: html, css, listview, javafx, colors

I have a ListView, containing folder paths, which display the folders which were added to the program.

I now, want to add a word in each entry, depending on if the folder is encrypted, I want to add the word 'encrypted' in green for example.

I tried adding a String with html color tags, however that does not work.

```
if (loadedFolders != null) {
    ObservableList<String> list = controller.folderList.getItems();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        
        StringBuilder read = new StringBuilder();
        read.append(list.get(i)).append("<html><font color='red'>test</font></html>");
        controller.folderList.getItems().set(i, read.toString());
    }
}
```

Importantly, only the added word should have a different color, the rest stays plain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use HTML to style Strings in JavaFX. What you need to do is add a style to the actual text that is being displayed in the `ListView`.

In order to do that, you'll need to implement your own `ListCell`. The `ListCell` is the actual cell that is being displayed for each item in your `ListView`. It can seem daunting at first, but it is fairly straightforward and is the only way you can selectively alter the way your data is displayed in the `ListView`.

Below is a complete sample application you can read through and run to see how it works.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListCellSample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        // **********************************************************************************************
        // Create a simple base layout
        // **********************************************************************************************
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));

        // Standard ListView for our sample data
        ListView<Sample> listView = new ListView<>();

        // Create some sample data for the ListView (some encrypted and others not)
        listView.getItems().addAll(
                new Sample("One", false),
                new Sample("Two", true),
                new Sample("Three", false),
                new Sample("Four", true)
                                  );

        // Add the ListView to the layout
        root.getChildren().add(listView);

        // **********************************************************************************************
        // Here we provide our own ListCell using the setCellFactory() method of the ListView
        // **********************************************************************************************
        listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<Sample>() {

            // Here we create the reusable layout for each cell. We will use an HBox for the root and labels
            // for the name of the Sample and it's encryption status
            final HBox root = new HBox(5);
            final Label sampleNameLabel = new Label();
            final Label encryptedLabel = new Label("Encrypted");

            // Set the style for the encryptedLabel in a static block
            {
                encryptedLabel.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: green; " +
                                        "-fx-font-style: italic;");

                // Add the sampleNameLabel to the root HBox. We will add the Encrypted label later, if needed
                root.getChildren().add(sampleNameLabel);
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Sample sample, boolean empty) {

                super.updateItem(sample, empty);

                if (sample == null || empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);

                    // Remove the encrypted label
                    root.getChildren().remove(encryptedLabel);
                } else {

                    // Set the sampleNameLabel to our sample's name
                    sampleNameLabel.setText(sample.getName());

                    // If the Sample is encrypted, add the encryptedLabel to our layout
                    if (sample.isEncrypted()) {
                        root.getChildren().add(encryptedLabel);
                    }

                    // Set our custom layout as the cell's graphic
                    setGraphic(root);
                }
            }
        });

        // Show the application
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

class Sample {

    private final String name;
    private final boolean encrypted;

    public Sample(String name, boolean encrypted) {

        this.name = name;
        this.encrypted = encrypted;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    public boolean isEncrypted() {

        return encrypted;
    }
}
```

And this is what you'll end up with:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: When I try this, it tells me "Type mismatch: cannot convert from new ListCell<String>(){} to  ListCell<String>"; My ListView is instantiated via an FXML loader

Comment: If your `ListView` is of type `String`, then this implementation will not work for you and you will not be able to style just parts of the text. However, if it is just a `String`, how is your `ListView` going to know whether the path is encrypted or not? You should use a model object as your `ListView` type (as I've done in the example).

Comment: I see, but when I replacement it with my Folder class, it still says the same

Comment: Then you're missing something. The `ListCell` type needs to match that of your `ListView`. So if you define it as `ListView<Folder>` then your `ListCell` should also be defined as `ListCell<Folder>`. There should be no `String` involved here.

Comment: If you continue to have issues, edit your question and include a [mcve] that demonstrates the error you're having and I can update my answer.

Comment: I fixed it by importing ListCell, eclipse just showed me the error and didnt suggest importing it